# Download images serially with async request

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

I want to download images from server asynchronously but they aren't coming serially. When I make a synchronous request then it downloads serially but creates other problems.

Code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){    
    NSString *UrlStr=urlString;

    NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[UrlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData *tempData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *imgData=[UIImage imageWithData:tempData];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        if (tempData!=nil) {

            ((FXImageView *)view).image = imgData;
            [_images addObject:imgData];

        }
        else{
            ((FXImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"];
            [_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"]];

        }

    });

})
```

i also tried `NSOperationQueue` but wasn't successful.

Comment: This downloads only one image. Can you show us a little more code where you queue up images for download?

Comment: its in - (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
method.

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.example.MyQueue", NULL);

dispatch_async(queue, ^(void){    
NSString *UrlStr=urlString;

NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:[UrlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *tempData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
UIImage *imgData=[UIImage imageWithData:tempData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    if (tempData!=nil) {

        ((FXImageView *)view).image = imgData;
        [_images addObject:imgData];

    }
    else{
        ((FXImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"];
        [_images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NoImage.png"]];

    }

});

})
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5

Not the same... I don't have rep to comments. I created a serial queue, u used a concurrent queue.. Follow the link to understand the theory behind.

Comment: This is the code posted in the question. How does it fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` set to `1`, but note that in this case you should implement your image download as `NSOperation` subclass. Please check out Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) on `NSOperation` to get a clue on how to implement asynchronous `NSOperation`.